# XMLDocument vs DataSet? Are They The Same Thing?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

Just a quick question.

Other than the way you manipulate them, are XMLDocuments and DataSets basically the same thing? I'm just wondering for speed issues.

I have come across some code  that calls dataSet.getXML() and then traverses the new XMLDocument.

I'm just curious what's the performance difference and which is the best one to use!

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very different.

A `DataSet` is a collection of related tabular records (with a strong focus on databases), including change tracking.

An `XmlDocument` is a tree structure of arbitrary data. You *can* convert between the two.

For "which is best".... what are you trying to do? *Personally* I very rarely (if ever) use `DataSet` / `DataTable`, but some people like them. I *prefer* an object (`class`) representation (perhaps via deserialization), but xml processing is fine in many cases.

It does, however, seem odd to write a `DataSet` to xml and then query the xml. In *that* scenario I would just access the original data directly.

Comment: I'm attempting to traverse through a DataSet and want to keep it inline with the rest of the code. I'm returned a DataSet from a third party DLL and was just curious about the performance differences

Comment: @Adam - the "performance differences" are going to be specific to your usage. You may want to profile, but first: does it work and is it *fast enough*. If so.... perhaps let it be?

Comment: I just did a few little tests and I think you're right, leaving it be may be the best bet. I have a DataSet that is well formed ready to traverse with very few lines of code versus the need to convert to an XMLDocument and navigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not. A DataSet does not store its internal data in XML and than a XMLDocument does not use a table/row structure to store XML Elements. You can convert from one to the other within severe limits but that's it. One of the biggest limitations is that a DataSet requires data to fit in a strict Table/Column format where a XmlDocument can have a wildly different structure from one XmlElement to the next. Moreover, the hierarchical structure of a XmlDocument usually doesn't map well to the tabular structure of a DataSet.

.NET provides XmlDataDocument as a way handle XML data in a tabular way. You have to remember though that XmlDataDocument is an XmlDocument first. The generated DataSet is just an alternative and limited way to look at the underlying XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your tables linq to xml or xquery might be faster to query your data than looking through the table. Im not positive on this, it is something you are going to have to test against your own data.

Comment: I'd love to use LINQ in some shape or form but the project is .NET 2.0 and I'm bound to the current assemblies I have!

Thanks for the reply though, I'm a big fan of LINQ though :)